# Receiving Error 1026 in AS3 and do not know why

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, constructor, syntax-error

I am getting error 1026 which is "Constructor functions must be instance methods" and I don't know why. I am creating a media player type program and am having trouble with my music portion. I made a function music player before this and copied the code over to my new project. The only thing that is different now is that the code is in a state and not the main.mxml file. This is my code below and I am receiving the error where it says "public var music:Sound;" I don't see why I am getting this error and any help would be appreciated!

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XML id="musicXML" source="data/musak.xml" />
    <s:XMLListCollection id="musicCollection" source="{musicXML.song}" />

</fx:Declarations>
<s:HGroup>
    <s:DataGrid id="musicGrid" dataProvider="{musicCollection}" click="onClick()" />
    <local:MusicPosition id="mProgress" width="319" height="83"/>

    <s:VGroup height="55">
        <s:Label text="Now playing: {musicGrid.selectedItem.@name}" />
        <s:Label id="txtPosition" width="91"/>
    </s:VGroup>

</s:HGroup>
<s:Button x="146" y="93" label="play" click="playMusic()"/>
<s:Button x="270" y="93" label="pause" click="pauseMusic()"/>
<fx:Script>

    <![CDATA[

        //set your variables
        public var music:Sound;
        [Bindable]public var musicChannel:SoundChannel;
        public var pausedTime:Number = 0;

        public function onClick():void {
            if(musicChannel) {
                musicChannel.stop();

                //clean up the variables
                music = null;
                musicChannel = null;

            }
            music = new Sound();
            music.load(new URLRequest(musicGrid.selectedItem.file.toString()));
            music.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMusicLoad);

        }

        public function onMusicLoad(e:Event):void {

            mProgress.update(0);
            //new channel
            musicChannel = music.play();


        }

        protected function onE(e:Event):void {
            if(musicChannel) {
                txtPosition.text = millisecondsToSeconds(musicChannel.position).toString() + "/" +
                    millisecondsToSeconds(music.length).toString();
                mProgress.update(musicChannel.position/music.length);

                mProgress.alpha = 1;
            } else 
                mProgress.alpha = 0;

        }

        protected function millisecondsToSeconds(milliseconds:Number):Number {
            return Math.round(milliseconds/1000);
        }

        public function pauseMusic():void {
            if(musicChannel) {
                pausedTime = musicChannel.position;
                musicChannel.stop();
            }
        }

        public function playMusic():void {
            if(musicChannel) {
                musicChannel = music.play(pausedTime);
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Comment: What is the name of the component this code is in?  What is the full component?  IS it a compile time error or a run time error?  If this is a class named music, for example, you may have issues trying to create a variable named 'music'.

Comment: I...feel very dumb. The class was named music as well. Changed the variable name and it worked. Thank you for pointing that out for me!

Comment: To help avoid these issues in the future (though obviously not entirely, be careful what you name things), **all** classes should be capitalized and camelcase whereas **all** function and object names should be camelcase but start with a lowercase letter. Only exceptions are with constants (which are generally in all-caps and separated by underscores)

Comment: Don't feel dumb; we all make mistakes. The trick is to continue to find new mistakes to make.  I posted that as a formal answer, and borrowed some of @Apocalyptic0n3 comments on common naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

Be very careful when naming thing.  You cannot create a variable, or method, inside your class that is the same name as the class itself.

A common--but not required--naming convention is this:

- Use CamelCase for classes.  In this case, your class would be named either Music.mxml or music.as.  Based on your code, it seems you already follow this convention with your MusicPosition class.
- Use camelcase for method, but make the first letter lowercase.  Your variable could be named music in this case.  Or, you may create a variable named musicPosition.  Remember in Flex, the id attribute of an MXML tag is the equivalent of a variable name.
- For constants, use all uppercase.  Constants are commonly used as event types.

Once, again, these are common conventions [in programming languages beyond Flex/ActionSCript] but are not required or enforced by the Flex SDK.

Comment: Yes, it's good to point out it's not required. Though it is generally expected by other developers who might view or maintain your code. It's personal preference, though it is widely accepted as standard at this point and it is just best to go with it.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 I've worked on a lot of projects that do not follow the naming conventions.

Comment: @Marty Wallace Isn't that convention only for private variables that are exposed via get set methods?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I've never worked on a project that didn't use the system described in your answer. And yeah, I've only seen underscores used for getters/setters. I know developers who frown upon using them even for that, though.